# For what value of $a$ is the volume of the following paraboloid split in half?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to figure out what value of $z=a$ would cause the volume of the following object (paraboloid) to be split to two halves:

$V={(x,y,z): x^2+y^2\leq z \leq1} $  with $0\leq a \leq 1$.

The answer is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

My attempt is :

[image: handwritten calculations]

Comment: Please write out your solution in MathJax. This helps people using screen readers, and prevents people from clicking links to external sites.

Comment: I commented on one of your previous questions as well that you should type in your key steps using mathjax, rather than adding an image. First of all, not everyone understands everyone's handwriting easily and image cannot be searched.

Comment: I tried adding it as a diagram and failed to do so. Looked it up but it didn't work

Comment: No diagram, type it in using mathjax. Your questions are not going to be well receive if you continue to keep uploading images.

Comment: So V1 is correct, and after switching the order of the integration of $dz$ and its bounds, I should receive V2? I can't really understand why the bounds of $z$ are not $a$ and $1$ for V2

Comment: because it is not a cylinder. What happens when radius is $\gt \sqrt a$? Will the vertical strip go from $z = a$ to $z = 1$?

Comment: Okay I think I understood what you meant. However, after switching the integration order and fixing the bounds for $r$ , the bounds for $z$ are supposed to be $a\rightarrow 1$ , no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are integrating in the order $dz$ first, the integral to find volume of region between $z = a$ and $z = 1$ will have to be split into two parts. For $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt a, a \leq z \leq 1$ and for $\sqrt a \leq r \leq 1, r^2 \leq z \leq 1$. It is easier to do this in order $dr$ first.

Then the integrals are,

$\displaystyle V_1 = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a \int_0^{\sqrt z} r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta$

$\displaystyle V_2 = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_a^1 \int_0^{\sqrt z} r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta$

Answer (score 0):

$V_1$ is correct.

$V_2 = \int_{a}^{1} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z}}drd\theta dz = \dfrac{\pi}{2}(1-a^2)$

Making it that:

$\dfrac{2a^2\pi}{4}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}(1-a^2)$

$ a=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$